# Could not json decode the token

Tags: php

Here is my code,

```
   <?php
session_start(); 
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/google-drive/index.php?msg=Successfully Uploaded!'; 
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
$client = new Google_Client();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$files = glob('files/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}

$uploaddir = 'files/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
}
$files= array();
$dir = dir('files');
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
$dir->close();

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $token = file_get_contents('auth.txt');
    echo $token;
    $token = array(
    'access_token' => 'xxxxxx',
    'token_type' =>'Bearer',
    'expires_in' =>'3600',
    'refresh_token' => 'xxxxx',
    'created' => 'xxxxxxx'
   );

 $tokennew = json_encode($token);
 $client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
    $client->setAccessToken($tokennew);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
        $file->setTitle($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
        $service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
            )
        );
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header('location:'.$url);
    exit;

}
include 'app.php'; 

?>
```

when I run this file I got 'Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Could not json decode the token'. I want to read access token from text file and pass to setAccessToken() function. access token prints well.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886132/uncaught-exception-google-auth-exception-with-message-could-not-json-decode-t .

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the content of your auth.txt ? The function `json_encode` is used to convert an array to a json object. The content of the auth.txt file should be in the right format. If the auth.txt contains a json object then you don't need to json_encode, instead use:

```
$client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('auth.txt'));
```

Comment: @Kristi Jorgji    see my edited code. now it gives invalid grant errror -- 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }' '

Answer (score 0):

That method `setAccessToken` in previous version expects the access token to be in a JSON encoded object. Update library, or use JSON encoded object:

```
$client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('auth.txt'));
```